# How to expend a variable with a quote, on the quote?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

Given the following string:

```
toto="function(param"
```

I want to get the substring `function` from the string above, in bash.

I tried the following:

```
echo "${toto%(}"
```

Which gives:

```
function(param
```

However, with this example:

```
echo "${toto%param}"
```

I get:

```
function(
```

As expected.

The expansion did not take place when expanding the the character "(".

Why is that ? How can I extract only the beginning (before the "(" of this string ?

Comment: Use `"${toto%(*}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cut `(` *and anything after it* you have match exactly that.

```
echo "${toto%(*}"
```